# How to add EC2 IP address to CloudFront WAF automatically after start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Our team has isolated instance of EC2 that's shutdown overnight to save resources. When it starts up, it has different IP address and they can't access it from internal network as its IP address has changed and need to be added to the WAF.

Is there a process via SNS, Lambda or something that I can run after launch that automates it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to create an [Elastic IP addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html), which is a static public IP address. Then, allocate that Elastic IP address to the Amazon EC2 instance.

The Elastic IP address will remain the same even when the instance is stopped and started.